# How to add text wrapping or char limit on an already formatted string

Tags: c#, string.format, character-limit

I have written some c# code that takes a csv file and displays in the console, I have used string.format to align both my heading and my column data however I have one string of data in a columns that it significantly longer in characters than the rest causing issue with alignment. Could someone either let me know if I can wrap text or add a character limit to my column named "boat name"

I have tried putting my current string.Format for DisplayMembers() into a variable and adding limit (0, 12) to this but it failed.

```
   public static void DisplayHeadings()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-4} {1,-7} {2,-10} {3,-8} {4,-20} {5,-8} {6,-10} {7,-6} {8,-6} {9, -9} {10, -5}"
            , "Pos", "BoatID", "Waterway", "Reg No", "Boat Name", "Length", "Homewater", "Beam", "Year", "Prop Pwr", "Prop"));
    }
    //string limit5 = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.".LimitLength(5);


    public static void DisplayMembers()
    {
        position = 1;

        foreach (var boat in boats)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-4} {1,-7} {2,-10} {3,-8} {4,-20} {5,-8} {6,-10} {7,-6} {8,-6} {9, -9} {10, -5}",
                position,
                boat.BoatId,
                boat.Waterway,
                boat.RegNo,
                boat.BoatName,
                boat.BoatLength,
                boat.HomeWaterway,
                boat.BoatBeam,
                boat.Year,
                boat.PropulsionPower,
                boat.Propulsion));
            position++;
```

// this all works and aligns as I want however boat.BoatName has one record which is about 30 characters compared to the others at around 10-12 chars.

limit chars on boat.BoatName to around 15 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following extension to limit the BoatName string.

```
public static class StringExts
{
    public static string CutStringIfNeeded(this string value, int maxCount)
    {
        return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && value.Length >= maxCount)
                   ? value.Substring(0, maxCount - 1)
                   : value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// returns the limited string or original one if less than 15 chars.
boat.BoatName.CutStringIfNeeded(15);
```

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what i needed to solve my issue thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction :)